# Integration of vine in iphone apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, ios4

Hi all I am iphone developer(trainee). I would like to integrate vine in my apps for sharing video and images. I have searched in google but unable to found link which help me. Please help me

Comment: Did you manage to implement it using the unofficial APIs?

Answer (score 1):

See [Vine.app API Reference](https://github.com/starlock/vino/wiki/API-Reference) Link